# Trying to set up a summary sheet for data validation

Tags: excel, validation

I've created a workbook for a friend who owns her own business. The workbook includes a sheet for each month, with Data Validation to determine the service, price, products, etc. It also indicates a method of payment.

She's asked that I update the summary sheet to not only show the totals per month, but to also show the total for each method of payment.

I'm having a hard time finding the right way to do this. Since this could change for each client, I imagine I'll have some sort of If statement, but I don't have enough experience to be able to successfully write this out (at least not in excel).

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Look up how to use array functions or pivot tables. Either will solve your problem.

Comment: I second the pivot table suggestion.